# Sublime Text 3 Themes In user/sublimelinter

Tags: sublimetext3, color-scheme

For some reason, when I change my color scheme in Sublime Text 3, a copy of it is placed in Application Support/Sublime Text 3/User/SublimeLinter!

Why should that even be? And how do I make it stop?

Comment: A copy of *what* is placed in Application Support/Sublime Text 3/User/SublimeLinter?  Also, are you using osx?

Comment: A copy of the color scheme. And yes, OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's happening. Sublime Linter needs to modify the active color scheme to add in it's own formats. So it copies, modifies, and saves the revised file in its own setting folder.